# Сортировка данных в алфавитном порядке. Язык C

Tags: c, сортировка

Есть программа-"База данных", у меня проблема в последней функции, которая должна отсортировывать данные в алфавитном порядке исходя из фамилий. Функцию я написал, но работает она коряво.

```
void SORT_DATA(FILE* fPtr)
{
    struct DATA blankClient, notebook= { 0,"","","",0,0,0,"",0,0 };

    int n = 0;
    while (fread(&notebook, sizeof(notebook), 1, fPtr))
    {
        fseek(fPtr, (n) * sizeof(struct DATA), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&blankClient, sizeof(struct DATA), 1, fPtr);
        if (blankClient.number != 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(notebook.surname, blankClient.surname) > 0)
            {
                blankClient.number--;
                notebook.number++;
                fseek(fPtr, (n - 1) * sizeof(struct DATA), SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(&blankClient, sizeof(struct DATA), 1, fPtr);
                fseek(fPtr, (n) * sizeof(struct DATA), SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(&notebook, sizeof(struct DATA), 1, fPtr);
            }
        }
        n++;
        fseek(fPtr, (n - 1) * sizeof(struct DATA), SEEK_SET);
    }

}
```

Вот так выглядит БД: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV8Fe.png

Подскажите, что не так в моем коде, и что нужно поменять?

Answer (score 0):

> что не так в моем коде

У Вас есть разные странные вещи в коде. Наприер, второй параметр в вызове

```
fseek(fPtr, (n - 1) * sizeof(struct DATA), SEEK_SET);
```

вполне может быть **отрицательным** числом. Но, самая главная проблема заключается в том, что Вы один и тот же файл (fPtr) пытаетесь просматривать одновременно двумя разными способами.

Первый - это :

```
while (fread(&notebook, sizeof(notebook), 1, fPtr))
```

А второй - это многочисленные чтения и записи после вызовов *fseek()*. Но ведь после первого же ручного позиционирования, **последовательный** просмотр в заголовке цикла будет нарушен. И вся Ваша сортировка потеряет всякий смысл.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/px0EaFJ.png попробовал метод пузырька, все равно ничего не выходит...(